Error in ph.x file
I ran this ph.x file for my structure. However, this response error was displayed. Observation: I made my scf file with norm conserving pseudopotential. The result was ok.
Input:
&inputph
  tr2_ph=1.0d-14,
  prefix='Si2CaP3O14',
  amass(1)=28.08550,
  amass(2)=40.07800,
  amass(3)=30.97376,
  amass(4)=15.99940,
  outdir='./tmp'
  epsil=.true.,
  ! lraman=.true.
  trans=.true.,
  asr=.true.
  fildyn='Si2CaP3O14.dyn'
 /
 0.0 0.0 0.0

Output:
Error in routine phq_readin (1):
     no elec. field with metals


The error is a little terse, but I assume this is saying you can't apply an electric field to a system containing metals (potentially Si depending on whether they mean just metals or semi-metals , but definitely Ca).

This means I cannot calculate FTIR and Ramam from this structure?

Did you use occupation='smearing' in your scf calculation? If yes, then that means you treated your material as a metal. And since metals have effectively infinite dielectric constant, it throws an error. Solution is: use epsil=.false. instead of epsil=.true.

I made the change you suggested, but the column with the IR values in the output file continues to show zero.
